# Exibir links na consulta do sql

Tags: php, mysql

Em um banco de dados (MySQL) eu possuo uma coluna dedicada a endereços eletrônicos (links).
O meu problema é: muitas vezes uma mesma linha pode possuir vários links. Eu gostaria de incluir os links no banco em uma mesma célula (Links), e na exibição, fazer um `href` ou algo do tipo, para que cada link seja clicável para o usuário, e não apareça um grudado no outro (exemplo: `www.google.com.brwww.youtube.comwww.facebook.com`).

Alguma ideia de como devo proceder ?

Comment: Você pode mudar a forma de gravação desses links?

Comment: O ideal é ter apenas um link por linha. Também é possivel fazer isso com varios links mas não é recomendado.

Comment: A forma que eu encontrei foi inserir registros repitidos, só mudando o link em cada re-inclusão.. mas fica muita coisa repetido e creio que pode deixar a consulta muito lenta..

Comment: Acho difícil agora mudar a forma de gravação do link, pois preciso terminar logo, mas estou aberto a sugestões..

Answer (score 1):

Existem varias formas pra fazer isso recomendo usar o serialize/unserialize.

```
<?php

$sites = array(
    'www.google.com',
    'www.terra.com.br',
    'www.globo.com'
);

$serializado = serialize($sites);

$lista = unserialize($serializado);
var_dump($serializado);
var_dump($lista);
```

ex. https://ideone.com/8GftAj

Ai só fazer um `foreach` para montar os links

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou testar.